# ng-bind-html values to other html tags

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I want to take data from ng-bind-html and bind it to some other html tags.Though i can directly use ng-bind-html for it. But is there any other way where we can use the binded html to other HTML tags?

**JS**:

```
 $scope.left = '<span>Hello World</span><strong>New Testing<strong><br/>h1>Testing</h1>';
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-bind-html="left" ng-model="GetValues"></div>

<span>{{GetValues}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Way 1 : Achieve with using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

html

```
<div my-directive="left" ng-model="GetValues"></div>
```

### directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlMain',function($scope){
    $scope.bindMe = {id:1,myvar:"test"};
});
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        varToBind: '=myDirective'     
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      outerList = '<span>Hello World</span><strong>New Testing<strong><br/>h1>Testing</h1>';
      outerList = $compile(outerList)(scope);
      elm.replaceWith(outerList);
    }
  }
});
```

### way 2: Achieve with using [AngularJS ng-include](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp)

> you can directly include a html file :)

```
<div ng-include="'myFile.htm'"></div>//your DOM string code should be in myfile.htm file
```

Answer (score 0):

use `trustAsHtml` to compile the string into Dom

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(html){
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

now call the function in the html

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(left)" ng-model="GetValues"></div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$sce){
 $scope.left = '<span>Hello World</span><strong>New Testing<strong><br/><h1>Testing</h1>';

  $scope.trustAsHtml = function(html){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(left)" ng-model="GetValues"></div>

<span>{{GetValues}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP asks for `any other directive for bind to html string`